# My Citroën C2 VTR won't start after putting a subwoofer in it

Tags: electrical, audio, citroen

My Citroën C2 VTR won't start after turning the key. It's making a click sound. This only started happening when I put a subwoofer in my car.   Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your sub-woofer has put a constant drain on the battery and is using up all the power. If you didn't do it, you should have hooked it up through switched power and run the power through the appropriate sized relay switch. This will ensure you don't get a current drain when the vehicle is off.

If you did do that, it still sounds like you have a constant drain on the battery. The battery may be used up as well and not charging like it should. Either way, the battery is dead by your description. You can try charging it disconnected from the vehicle, but I would suspect you'll run into the same situation if it does charge. If it doesn't take a charge, you'll likely need to change out the battery.